# cocos creatorとネイティブの連携方法

Tags: javascript, swift, java, webview

cocos creator　の　webアプリケーションとネイティブの連携方法を教えてください。

JS <- -> swift, java
相互にメソッドを呼び出したいです。

cocos creatorでビルドしたwebアプリをネイティブアプリのwebviewで動作させます。
そのwebviewで動くcocos（JS）とネイティブの連携をしたいです